# Moodle Dates When User Completed Course

Tags: mysql, moodle

I am trying to get the dates for when a user has last completed the course, I have the following working SQL but its giving the wrong dates.

I have dates for all modules, but know they are wrong as there a couple of months old, and I know 1 course was completed yesterday.

```
SELECT
u.username,
c.shortname,        
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(gi.timemodified), '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'date'
FROM moodle.user u
JOIN moodle.grade_grades g ON g.userid = u.id
JOIN moodle.grade_items gi ON g.itemid =  gi.id
JOIN moodle.course c ON c.id = gi.courseid
WHERE u.email = ?
GROUP BY c.shortname
```

Answer (score 3):

The course completions should be in `mdl_course_completions`

```
SELECT u.username,
       c.shortname,        
       cc.timecompleted
FROM mdl_course_completions cc
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = cc.course
JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id = cc.userid
WHERE u.email = :email
```

Comment: Cant use that one as the course completions table is empty. But thanks for the suggestion. +1

Comment: Which version of Moodle are you using? and have you enabled course completion? https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Course_completion

Comment: That I dont know, its a standalone system I dont have access to, all I have been given is readonly connection to the database to pull information

Comment: The release will be the human Moodle version and enablecompletion is a boolean value - `SELECT *
FROM mdl_config
WHERE name IN ('release', 'enablecompletion')`